# Erro ao enviar e-mail com PHPMAILER

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

Olá, segue o código:

```
Inicia a classe PHPMailer
$mail = new PHPMailer();


$mail->IsSMTP(); 
$mail->Host = "smtp.dominio.com"; 
$mail->Username = 'suporte@dominio.com'; // Usuário do servidor SMTP
$mail->Password = 'senha123'; // Senha do servidor SMTP


$mail->From = "email@dominio.com.br"; 
$mail->FromName = "meu dominio"; 



$mail->AddAddress("meuemail","meunome");

$mail->IsHTML(true); 

$mail->Subject  = "Confirmação de pagamento";
$mail->Body = "meu email em html..";


$enviado = $mail->Send();


$mail->ClearAllRecipients();
$mail->ClearAttachments();


if ($enviado) {
echo "E-mail enviado com sucesso!";
} else {
echo "Não foi possível enviar o e-mail.<br /><br />";
echo "<b>Informações do erro:</b> <br />" . $mail->ErrorInfo;
}
```

**Segue o erro:**

> NÃ£o foi possÃ­vel enviar o e-mail.
>
> InformaÃ§Ãµes do erro: SMTP connect() failed.NÃ£o foi possÃ­vel enviar
>   o e-mail.
>
> InformaÃ§Ãµes do erro: SMTP connect() failed.

Enfim, já ocorreu este erro com alguém? E qual foi o motivo?
Já habilitei a linha ssl lá no php.ini que ouvi alguns dizerem que precisava..

Comment: Setou a porta e o tipo de segurança no phpMailer?

Comment: Não havia setado, mas setei para fins de testes, mas o erro persisti.
Setei estas duas linhas:
`$mail->Port = 465;
$mail->SMTPAuth = true; `

Agradeço pela ajuda perdeu.

Comment: Resolvido, a host estava errada, confundi o domínio como sendo uma host, que na verdade é onde o domínio está hospedado.. a porta usei 587, obrigado a todos!

Comment: Se a versao do seu Script for atual, do PHPmailer, o seu servidor é para está na versao 5+ do PHP. Verifique isso na sua hospedagem.

Comment: Entendo, mas o erro em questão foi confundir dominio com hospedagem, estava colocando ali na Host o dominio do site qu estava usando, e não o dá hospedagem, e também coloquei a posta 587.
Vou marca-lo como útil, pois de fato é necessário atualizar lá no CPANEL do site o PHP.

Answer (score 1):

Troque o `require('class.phpmailer.php');` por `require('PHPMailerAutoload.php');`

Não esqueça de verificar se você tem o arquivo **PHPMailerAutoload.php** na pasta aonde você está chamando o PHPMailer

Comment: Tenho sim, e fiz essa alteração e o erro persiste, agradeço a ajuda Alisson.